# Signature help docs missing

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, settings, documentation, gopls

I want VSCode to function how it does in the VSCode (golang) demo, and how it used to work on a previous install.

Can anybody provide the `setting.json needed for this?

The VSCode demo, [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/go#_intellisense) & [here](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/master/README.md), shows the docs (`Signature Help`) displayed next to the function (`Code completion`).

On my new install of `vscode:v1.76.2` `gopls:v0.11.0`  `go:v1.20.1` the `Signature help` is missing. Admittedly the docs are displayed once inside the functions `()` as stated in the VSCode documentations [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/go#_signature-help), however this dual `Code completion and Signature Help` used to exist and I'd like it back.

### How I want VSCode to work:

*From VSCode demo, help while in code complete*
[image]
[image: Snippet from VSCode docs]

### Demonstration of my current setup:

*Signature help missing until inside function*
[image: Demonstration of my current setup]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the "More" panel of the `Code completion`. Hover on the current item and a chevron right icon will show up. Click that icon to toggle the "More" panel.

[image]

Comment: Thank you.
This is not immediately obvious as the chevron doesn't appear until there's a mouse hover event, and I don't use a mouse often. For anyone else wondering, once clicked the docs will remains enabled until the X (close) button is clicked to disable them.